# AS3 memory leak while scaling movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a Movieclip which contains Bitmaps and Textfields. It is quite large in memory, but not problematic.

Problem arises when I try to scale the Movieclip in each frame, making a tween animation. Code is simple:

`actor.scaleX += (targetScale - actor.scaleX) * ANIMATION_SPEED;`

The problem is, it leaks memory like crazy. I am sure this line causes the problem, because when I comment it out, memory leak is no more.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try turning cacheAsBitmap for that MC to false.

Comment: Do you have any alpha <1 on your actor and nested sprites? Setting blendMode to 'alpha' maybe helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I have already tried cacheAsBitmap to no avail. 

I am also tweening alpha values, but it doesn't seem to cause the leak, because scaling without using alpha values also causes memory leak. I've tried to change the blendMode to alpha, it just gave me invisible Movieclips.

Comment: Are you sure your memory actually leaks rather than just jumps in a "saw" style?

Comment: Yes I am sure of it. It goes up to 1GB and further. I am using the miner for it: http://www.as3gamegears.com/debug/the-miner/